# How to duplicate a post http request with files without curl?

Tags: php, http, curl

I want to duplicate a HTTP POST request from a form which includes file elements, as if there were just 2 action attributes with different targets on the form element.

So far I have not been able to do this successfully with cURL for one reason or another, so I'm looking for alternatives (that don't use the cURL library what-so-ever, therefore no pecl_http)

Comment: What's the problem with using cURL, maybe you should show us your code?

Comment: Well so far I've been having a lot of trouble getting it to work with my array of files, for some reason it will accept single file fields but not arrays, and beause it will be somebody's next question yes I am addding the '@'... I've tried converting the file array to a single dimensional array, however the file gets 'corrupted' and loses its file type when I send that way (just using '@'.$file['tmp_name']

Comment: You should still post your code. By "losing filetype", do you mean the file name extension? Because the `'tmp_name'` field of file uploads doesn't have an extension...

Comment: Nope not the extension, if I send the file over cURL, then do a print_r($_FILES) on the receiving side, I get...

    [srubch] => Array
        (
            [name] => php5QMPOU
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJ5uvTa
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 71189
        )

And the file will not work. I'm considering not using files at all, but just reading the content of the file in as binary, serializing, then unserialising and writing the file on the recieving end

Comment: If you edit the question, to reflect the problems you're having, we can likely help you solve them.  However, please edit the question and use the formatting features.  Syntax can already be annoying enough to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is [http_request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-request.php), but that is a PECL extension.  I think you're better off using cURL, as that is typically available in PHP installs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external curl, lwp-request, or maybe even wget.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's not easy.

You'd have to either manually craft a "multipart/form-data" request, or rewrite the Content-type header using Apache so as to prevent the file data from being parsed and the use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` or `php://input`. How to do both has been answered in SO before, but I'm not being able to find any of the questions.